# Bypassing the duplicate title filter by deleting, then undeleting

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, title, quality-filter

We cannot normally post questions with same title that already exist, but I managed to break that rule.

1. I posted a question with the unique title and then I deleted it.
2. Then I posted the same question with the same title.
3. Then I simply undeleted my previous question and there I was with two questions with same title.

Comment: Sure, there are ways of abusing this. I doubt such filters are there to be foolproof. They are there to encourage you to ask good questions and improve your chances of being received well. Duplicating your question like that will not end well for your account in the long run, but you'd only have yourself to blame.

Comment: **Not to do**, but technically you can also temporary edit to a different title, then rollback the edit: the rollback will bypass the filter and requires less Reputation than undeletion of someone else post.

Answer (score 5):

That filter is meant to prevent you from asking a question with the title of a question that already exists.

Sure, by posting the earlier question yourself you can delete and then undelete it, but generally, you don't own the post bearing the title you want to use - so you cannot delete it.

Comment: but when i delete my previous question the system should not let me post the same question again. because it knows i can undelete my previous question any time. which would post duplicate questions. I can even see both of my duplicate questions in search

Comment: @Ahti but that would mean that *every* deleted question's title should forevermore be reserved. This would be very confusing, because the system would tell you a question with that name already existed, but you wouldn't be able to see it.